# How much are retained players supposed to be paid in the IPL?

Tags: cricket, finances, indian-premier-league

After the IPL auction, we know the amount that teams bought the players for and they will be paid according to that.

But I couldn't find the amount that retained players are to be paid.

It's not available in [this list](http://www.espncricinfo.com/ipl2014_auction/content/site/ipl2014_auction/index.html).

Who determines the amount retained players will be paid in the IPL? Is it negotiable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For retained players the salary cap will be charged as follows.

> **For Capped Players**
>
> - Rs. 12.5 crores for the first capped Player so retained
> - Rs. 9.5 crores for the second capped Player so retained
> - Rs. 7.5 crores for the third capped Player so retained
> - Rs. 5.5 crores for the fourth capped Player so retained
> - Rs. 4 crores for the fifth capped Player so retained
>
> **For Uncapped Players**
>
> - Rs. 4 crores for each uncapped Player so retained

[Source.](http://www.iplt20.com/news/2013/announcements/4248/pepsi-ipl-2014-player-regulations)

Comment: The above amounts are non-negotiable. Stipulated by IPL Committee